# I can't Create a account in UVA Online Judge

Tags: account, confirmation, cuda-uva

I fill up the form but I need a email confirmation but when I check my email I cannot find the confirmation email. That's why I can't create a account. How I fix this problem?

How I can create e UVA online judge account where I can solve the problem of c programming?  I tried so many times even I check spam emails but I can not find any confirmation email.

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct place to raise this question. Mostly technical discussions happen here

Answer (score 0):

Same here for password recovery or create new account. I send an email to de groups from uva contact list

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. It seems to be a problem with the website which keeps repeating every now and then for the past few years.

A solution is to use a virtual judge like vjudge: https://vjudge.net/

In this website, you have the option to select the platform (UVa) and choose the problem Number